# Creating automatic fill in word document with drop-down list content control

Tags: vba, ms-word

firt of all I need to admit, that I know absolutely nothing about creating macros in Word, but I would like to make it a little easier for myself to work on documents at my workplace, and to that end I would like to create a macro that will change the text in a Word document depending on the option selected in the drop-down list content control.

For example, in the drop-down list inserted into a Word document I have:

- option 1
- option 2

If I select option 1 from the list, I want the text assigned to option 1 to appear in a specific place in the Word document.
If I change the selection from option 1 to option 2, I want the text assigned to option 1 to be replaced by the text assigned to option 2.
If neither option is selected, I want no text to be displayed at that particular location in the document.

Is it at all possible to create code for a macro that would work in this way? If so, I would appreciate your help.

I tried to describe this in GPT chat, but what I was getting did not work exactly as I described above. The effect of working with GPT chat was that the text would only appear if one of the options was already selected when I ran the macro in Word. What's more, the macro created by GPT chat did not respond by changing the text when I selected an option other than the one that was selected when the macro was run.

This is the code I got from ChatGPT:

```
Sub Makro6()
    Dim cc As Contentcontrol
    Dim selectedValue As String
    
    For Each cc In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
        If cc.Title = "Subsystem" Then
            selectedValue = cc.Range.Text
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cc
    
    Select Case selectedValue
        Case "Option1"
            UpdateOrCreateBookmark "Option_1", "Text for Option1"
            ToggleBookmarkVisibility "Option_1", True
            ToggleBookmarkVisibility "Option_2", False
        Case "Option2"
            UpdateOrCreateBookmark "Option_1", "Text for Option2"
            ToggleBookmarkVisibility "Option_1", False
            ToggleBookmarkVisibility "Option_2", True
        Case Else
            ToggleBookmarkVisibility "Option_1", False
            ToggleBookmarkVisibility "Option_2", False
    End Select
End Sub

Sub UpdateOrCreateBookmark(bookmarkName As String, bookmarkText As String)
    Dim bm As Bookmark
    On Error Resume Next
    Set bm = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bookmarkName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If bm Is Nothing Then
        ' Bookmark does not exist add new one
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add bookmarkName, Selection.Range
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bookmarkName).Range.Text = bookmarkText
    Else
        ' Bookmark exists update its text
        bm.Range.Text = bookmarkText
    End If
End Sub

Sub ToggleBookmarkVisibility(bookmarkName As String, visible As Boolean)
    Dim bm As Bookmark
    On Error Resume Next
    Set bm = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bookmarkName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If bm Is Nothing Then
        ' Bookmark does not exist
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ' Show/hide bookmark
        bm.Range.Font.Hidden = Not visible
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: As far as I know this should only be WordVBA basic capabilities, not difficult to achieve. It's just that your problem scenario is too general and not specific enough. For example, why do you want to use the options box *(or "drop-down list " as you mentioned )* to operate? And how to do it? How to present what you want, you should add to understand easilier and clearer, preferably with a demonstration video or images.

Comment: My work involves writing similar documents that differ in certain details, and it is these details in the text that I want to automate in order to avoid mistakes in the document. Therefore, I would like to create one universal document template. For example, I have two similar documents to write. One will be about option 1, the other about option 2. That is why I wanted to insert a drop-down box in the document template and these dependencies.
Here are screenshots:
https://i.postimg.cc/BQkdsfQY/option1.png
https://i.postimg.cc/4xcjx2YJ/option2.png

Answer (score 0):

Now you can try it again to see if this is what you want.

Good luck!

demo:
https://youtube.com/live/AgX3gNKDhb4?feature=share

## code

### The original code

#### code in Module

```vb
Sub Makro6()
    Dim cc As ContentControl
    Dim selectedValue As String, bookmarkName As String
    
    For Each cc In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
        If cc.Title = "Subsystem" Then '"Subsystem" is what you Name(Title) the drop-down listBox
            selectedValue = cc.Range.Text
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cc
    
    'not found cc.Title = "Subsystem"
    If cc Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
'    Else
'        Dim combo As ComboBox
'        Set combo = cc.DropdownListEntries
    End If
    
    'add item(Entries) to the drop-down listBox
    If cc.DropdownListEntries.Count = 1 Then 'Text= "選擇一個項目。" ; Value="" 'this is what default showing in my traditional Chinese version MS Word
        With cc.DropdownListEntries
            'the second argument(named "Value") is the text which be printed in doc
            .Add "Option1", "option 1"
            .Add "Option2", "option 2"
        End With
        
    End If
    
    bookmarkName = "Option"
    Dim bm As Bookmark
    For Each bm In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        If bm.Name = bookmarkName Then Exit For
    Next
    Rem When inserting text for the first time, you must place the insertion point in the appropriate position.
    'Afterwards, as long as the location still exists in the document (bookmark ,whose name is the value of the variable bookmarkName, still exists), it is not necessary.
    'this part is add after the demo
    If bm Is Nothing Then
        'bookmark (text which to insert to the doc ) can not in the listBox
        'where to print the text you selected,where to place the insertion point
        If Selection.Information(wdInContentControl) Then
            MsgBox "Please place the insertion point in the appropriate position!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    'get the data in DropdownListEntries to print out at the specific position in the doc 
    Dim e As ContentControlListEntry, Text2Show As String
    For Each e In cc.DropdownListEntries
        If e = selectedValue Then
            ' this is the second argument in the method Add 
             ' of the DropdownListEntries object above 
            Text2Show = e.Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next e
    'base on your code given by chatGPT so still use bookmark to do
    UpdateOrCreateBookmark bookmarkName, Text2Show '"Text for Option1" …… etc.

End Sub

Sub UpdateOrCreateBookmark(bookmarkName As String, bookmarkText As String)
    Dim bm As Bookmark, rng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set bm = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bookmarkName)
    On Error GoTo 0
   
   
    If bm Is Nothing Then
        ' Bookmark does not exist add new one
        Set rng = Selection.Range
        rng.Text = bookmarkText
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add bookmarkName, rng 'Selection.Range
'        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bookmarkName).Range.Text = bookmarkText
    Else
        ' Bookmark exists update its text
        Set rng = bm.Range
        Rem "If neither option is selected, I want no text to be displayed at that particular location in the document."
        'bm.Range.Text = bookmarkText
        rng.Text = bookmarkText 'as soon as bm.Range.Text = "" then the bookmark will be kill
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add bookmarkName, rng 'rebuild the bookmark at the same position
    End If
End Sub
```

#### code in ThisDocument object

*cocode with YouChat, chatGPT*：

In Word VBA, there is no similar "On Value Changed" event for ContentControl controls (including drop-down lists, comboboxs, etc. ). However, you can use the **Document.ContentControlOnExit event** to listen for changes to the ContentControl control.

[ContentControlOnExit event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.contentcontrolonexit?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Dzh-TW%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm4001012)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) is triggered when the user takes the focus off of the ContentControl control. In this event handler, you can check if the input value has changed, and if the value has changed, you can execute the relevant code. Here is the demo code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnEnter(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl)
    ContentControl.Tag = ContentControl.Range.Text
End Sub

Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
    If ContentControl.Type = wdContentControlComboBox And ContentControl.Title = "Subsystem" Then
        'Dim OldValue As String
        'Dim NewValue As String
        
        If ContentControl.Range.Text <> ContentControl.Tag Then
        'OldValue = ContentControl.Tag
        'NewValue = ContentControl.Range.Text
        'If OldValue <> NewValue Then
            Makro6
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

So you **have to leave the combobox after your selecting having changed** to make the code run the function. Have fun!

If you use **UserForm** or **ActiveX control** , *not* **ContentControl** to implement, it should be more flexible。

For example, if you add one ActiveX control **ComboBox1** into the doc, when you double click on it, it will automatically add the ComboBox1_Change() event handlers procedures into the **ThisDocument** object like below :

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    rem you can write the code here to do what you want something like Sub Makro6 
End Sub
```

it means as soon as you change your selected item in the Combobox1, the code written in the block will do its job.

> *After this learning process, I realized the difference between **ContentControl** and **ActiveX controls (or Form object)**, and ContentControl is really a good name, it is **really the Control of the Word Document Content** Range. or on the addition of an "outer box", that is, in/on a content range, plus a simulation / such as Control of things (object) only. It indeed is not independent of the content of the Word document/range. So its value is just the value of the Word document range itself, hence it is also in the Control and the document content, free to move (move out / move in), that is, you can move directly up and down left and right just by press the corresponding key in and out without any hindrance. **Content Control** is really what the name can mean.*

### The new code

the code in the [**sample file**](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tb_rpAp4fc6Y_LcZQ8PnUhR2_5lAK5rS?rtpof=true&usp=drive_fs)

#### code in Module1

```vb
Option Explicit

'the Title property of ContentControl's value
Public Const ContentControlTitle As String = "Subsystem"

'The name of the bookmark used as an insertion location
Public Const bookmarkName As String = "Option"

'Option1 's Value to Insert a Specific Range
Public Option1ValueInsertSpecificRange As String
'Option2 's Value to Insert a Specific Range
Public Option2ValueInsertSpecificRange As String

Dim selectedValue As String

Public d As Document


'initiate the two Options' Values to Insert a Specific Range in an active document
Sub initiateOptionValue()
    If d Is Nothing Then Set d = ActiveDocument
    
    Dim p1 As Paragraph, p2 As Paragraph
    Set p1 = d.Paragraphs(1): Set p2 = d.Paragraphs(2)
    
    Rem You can use an range in the document as the setting for these two values, as illustrated here by the paragraph
    Option1ValueInsertSpecificRange = Left(p1.Range.Text, Len(p1.Range.Text) - 1)
    Option2ValueInsertSpecificRange = Left(p2.Range.Text, Len(p2.Range.Text) - 1)
'    Option1ValueInsertSpecificRange = "option 1"
'    Option2ValueInsertSpecificRange = "option 2"
End Sub

Rem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76240148/creating-automatic-fill-in-word-document-with-drop-down-list-content-control

Sub Makro6(rng As Range)
    Dim cc As ContentControl, ur As UndoRecord
        
    If d Is Nothing Then Set d = ActiveDocument
    
    Set cc = GetCC
'    For Each cc In d.ContentControls
'        If cc.Title = ContentControlTitle Then 'ContentControlTitle="Subsystem" is what you Name(Title) the drop-down listBox
'            selectedValue = cc.Range.Text
'            Exit For
'        End If
'    Next cc
    
    'not found cc.Title = "Subsystem"(the ContentControlTitle value)
    If cc Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        selectedValue = cc.Range.Text
'        Dim combo As ComboBox
'        Set combo = cc.DropdownListEntries
    End If
    
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "Makro6"
    
    'add item(Entries) to the drop-down listBox
    If cc.DropdownListEntries.Count = 1 Then 'Text= "選擇一個項目。" ; Value="" 'this is what default showing in my traditional Chinese version MS Word
        With cc.DropdownListEntries
            initiateOptionValue
            'the second argument(named "Value") is the text which be printed in doc
            .Add "Option1", Option1ValueInsertSpecificRange
            .Add "Option2", Option2ValueInsertSpecificRange
        End With
    Else
        Dim item As ContentControlListEntry
        initiateOptionValue
        For Each item In cc.DropdownListEntries
            With item
                'the second argument(named "Value") is the text which be printed in doc
                Select Case .Text
                    Case "Option1"
                        If .Value <> Option1ValueInsertSpecificRange Then
                            .Value = Option1ValueInsertSpecificRange
                        End If
                    Case "Option2"
                        If .Value <> Option2ValueInsertSpecificRange Then
                            .Value = Option2ValueInsertSpecificRange
                        End If
                End Select
            End With
        Next item
    End If
    
    
    Dim bm As Bookmark
    For Each bm In d.Bookmarks
        If bm.Name = bookmarkName Then Exit For
    Next
    Rem When inserting text for the first time, you must place the insertion point in the appropriate position.
    'Afterwards, as long as the location still exists in the document (bookmark ,whose name is the value of the variable bookmarkName, still exists), it is not necessary.
    'this part is add after the demo
    If bm Is Nothing Then
        'bookmark (text which to insert to the doc ) can not in the listBox
        'where to print the text you selected,where to place the insertion point
        'If Selection.Information(wdInContentControl) Then
        If rng.Information(wdInContentControl) Then
            MsgBox "Please place the insertion point in the appropriate position!", vbExclamation
            ur.EndCustomRecord
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    'get the data in DropdownListEntries to print out at the specific position in the doc
    Dim e As ContentControlListEntry, Text2Show As String
    For Each e In cc.DropdownListEntries
        If e = selectedValue Then
            ' this is the second argument in the method Add
             ' of the DropdownListEntries object above
            Text2Show = e.Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next e
    'base on your code given by chatGPT so still use bookmark to do
    UpdateOrCreateBookmark bookmarkName, rng, Text2Show '"Text for Option1" …… etc.

    ur.EndCustomRecord
End Sub

Sub UpdateOrCreateBookmark(bookmarkName As String, rng As Range, bookmarkText As String)
    Dim bm As Bookmark
    On Error Resume Next
    Set bm = d.Bookmarks(bookmarkName)
    On Error GoTo 0
   
   
    If bm Is Nothing Then
        ' Bookmark does not exist add new one
        'Set rng = Selection.Range
        rng.Text = bookmarkText
        d.Bookmarks.Add bookmarkName, rng 'Selection.Range
'        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bookmarkName).Range.Text = bookmarkText
    Else
        ' Bookmark exists update its text
        Set rng = bm.Range
        Rem "If neither option is selected, I want no text to be displayed at that particular location in the document."
        'bm.Range.Text = bookmarkText
        rng.Text = bookmarkText 'as soon as bm.Range.Text = "" then the bookmark will be kill
        
        d.Bookmarks.Add bookmarkName, rng 'rebuild the bookmark at the same position
    End If
    
'        Dim cc As ContentControl
'        Set cc = GetCC
'        Select Case cc.Range.Text
        Select Case GETSelectedValue
            Case "Option1"
                rng.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
            Case "Option2"
                rng.Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
        End Select

End Sub


Function GetCC() As ContentControl
    If d Is Nothing Then Set d = ActiveDocument
    
    Dim cc As ContentControl
    For Each cc In d.ContentControls
        If cc.Title = ContentControlTitle Then 'ContentControlTitle="Subsystem" is what you Name(Title) the drop-down listBox
            Set GetCC = cc
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cc
End Function

Function GetBookmark() As Bookmark
    If d Is Nothing Then Set d = ActiveDocument
    
    Dim bm As Bookmark
    For Each bm In d.Bookmarks
        If bm.Name = bookmarkName Then
            Set GetBookmark = bm
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next bm
End Function

Property Get GETSelectedValue() As String
    GETSelectedValue = selectedValue
End Property
```

#### code in Systems

```vb
Option Explicit

'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/objects-properties-methods/using-events-with-the-application-object-word
Public x As New app 'This is what is called creating a "new" class of modules - actually creating a reference to it.' The original online description is also in Dim.

Public SelectionPreviousRange As New VBA.Collection

Public Sub Register_Event_Handler() 'The registry procedure to make the custom object class module active. See "Events using Application Object".
    Set x.appWord = Word.Application 'This allows the new object to be associated with the Word.
End Sub
```

#### code in ThisDocument

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnEnter(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl)
    'Once cursor into the ContentControl, exam and set the document to be manipulated
    
    Dim cc As ContentControl
    Set cc = GetCC
    
    If GetBookmark() Is Nothing Then
    'If cc.DropdownListEntries.Count = 1 Then
        If d Is Nothing Then Set d = ActiveDocument
        'the first time into here run Makro6 to build the list of items and insert range
        If SelectionPreviousRange.Count > 0 Then
            Makro6 IIf(SelectionPreviousRange(1) Is Nothing, Selection.Range, SelectionPreviousRange(1))
        Else
            Makro6 Selection.Range
        End If
    End If
    
    
    ContentControl.Tag = ContentControl.Range.Text
End Sub

Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
    If ContentControl.Type = wdContentControlComboBox And ContentControl.Title = ContentControlTitle Then
'        Dim OldValue As String
'        Dim NewValue As String
        
        If ContentControl.Range.Text <> ContentControl.Tag Then
        'OldValue = ContentControl.Tag
        'NewValue = ContentControl.Range.Text
        'If OldValue <> NewValue Then
            If SelectionPreviousRange.Count > 0 Then
                Makro6 IIf(SelectionPreviousRange(1) Is Nothing, Selection.Range, SelectionPreviousRange(1))
            Else
                Makro6 Selection.Range
            End If

        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Document_Open()
    'Registering event handlers
    Register_Event_Handler
End Sub
```

#### code in app *class module*

```vb
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents appWord As Word.Application


 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.windowselectionchange
Private Sub appWord_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
 'Sel.Font.Bold = True
' Stop
    Dim bm As Bookmark, cc As ContentControl
    On Error Resume Next
    Set bm = d.Bookmarks(bookmarkName)
    On Error GoTo 0
      
    If Not bm Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Set cc = GetCC
    If cc Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    getPreviousRange

End Sub

Private Sub getPreviousRange()
    Rem cocode with chatGPT
    SelectionPreviousRange.Add Selection.Range.Duplicate
    If SelectionPreviousRange.Count > 2 Then
        SelectionPreviousRange.Remove 1
    End If
End Sub
```

#### Sample File

The code has been improved *(see above the new code section)*.

[**sample file**, download and check it out](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tb_rpAp4fc6Y_LcZQ8PnUhR2_5lAK5rS?rtpof=true&usp=drive_fs)

[DEMO VIDEO](https://youtube.com/live/4yVlDI8JN8U?feature=share)

- In this file, you can write the text you want to insert when Option1 is selected in the first paragraph and the text you want to insert when Option2 is selected in the second paragraph
- After selecting the location where you want to insert the text, click the drop-down list content control to insert the text you want in that specified location.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your effort! This is almost what I meant in my original post. What I meant is that when on 3:49 of your youtube video you choose from the drop-down list option1, the text for the option1 in the document appears automatically (with no need of clicking this "play button" in the VBA editor), and when the option2 is chosen instead of option1, then text assigned for option2 replaces the text assigned for option 1 (and it also happens with no need of clicking this "play button" in the VBA editor).

Comment: @NW ok try it yourself with my updated code. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'll try it out as soon as I can.

Comment: @NW I've added the sample file at the end of my answer, you can download and check it out.