# Display Excel data in a specific location in my Word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I need to write VBA code to select information from 3 columns of my Excel document and transpose it into a Word document template. The Word document I need to use has two fixed parts and I want my code to run in a way that displays the Excel data in the middle of my Word document. To do this, I thought of adding a bookmark in my Word document to indicate where I want the Excel content to appear, then in my VBA code, have it said: 'At bookmark , run the next code block.' And to achieve this, I planned to assign my code block to a variable, 'VBAcode='...my code...'.

The problem I'm facing here is that I'm unable to "wrap" all of my code so it can be assigned to 'VBAcode' because it's too long (about 40 lines), knowing that each line has to be enclosed in quotes from what I understand.

I also tried to place 3 bookmarks to indicate the location where I want the text of my three columns to appear but knowing that my column 1 corresponds to chapter names, column 2 to subchapter names and column 3 has description names, the problem was that it displayed me all the chapters at bookmark 1, then all the sub-chapter names at bookmark 2, etc, without keeping the correct tree structure.

Do you have any ideas on how I could accomplish this, or if there is another method to display my code in a specific location in my Word document? Thanks in advance!

Here my bloc code:

```vb
        ' Déclarer la collection pour stocker les chapitres déjà traités
        Dim chapitresTraités As Collection
        Set chapitresTraités = New Collection
        
        ' Récupérer les plages de données à partir d'Excel
        Dim lastRowChapitre As Long
        Dim lastRowSousChapitre As Long
        Dim lastRowDescription As Long
        
        ' Plage des chapitres
        lastRowChapitre = r.Offset(1, 7).End(xlDown).Row
        Set rngChapitre = r.Offset(1, 7).Resize(lastRowChapitre - r.Row, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        
        ' Parcourir les données dans Excel et les ajouter à Word
    For Each chapitre In rngChapitre
        ' Vérifier si le chapitre actuel a déjà été traité
        On Error Resume Next
        chapitresTraités.Add chapitre.Value, CStr(chapitre.Value)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            ' Le chapitre existe déjà, passer au chapitre suivant
            Err.Clear
            On Error GoTo 0
            GoTo NextChapitre
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        ' Ajouter le chapitre comme un nouveau paragraphe avec le style "Titre 1"
        Document.Content.InsertParagraphAfter
        Document.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Text = chapitre.Value
        Document.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Style = Document.styles("Titre 1")
        
        ' Récupérer la plage des sous-chapitres correspondant au chapitre actuel
        lastRowSousChapitre = r.Offset(1, 9).End(xlDown).Row
        Set rngSousChapitre = r.Offset(1, 9).Resize(lastRowSousChapitre - r.Row, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        
        ' Déclarer la collection pour stocker les sous-chapitres déjà traités
        Dim sousChapitresTraités As Collection
        Set sousChapitresTraités = New Collection
        
        For Each sousChapitre In rngSousChapitre
            ' Vérifier si le sous-chapitre correspond au chapitre actuel et s'il n'a pas déjà été traité
            If sousChapitre.Offset(0, -2).Value = chapitre.Value Then
                On Error Resume Next
                sousChapitresTraités.Add sousChapitre.Value, CStr(sousChapitre.Value)
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    ' Le sous-chapitre existe déjà, passer au sous-chapitre suivant
                    Err.Clear
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    GoTo NextSousChapitre
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
                
                ' Ajouter le sous-chapitre comme un nouveau paragraphe avec le style "Titre 2"
                Document.Content.InsertParagraphAfter
                Document.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Text = sousChapitre.Value
                Document.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Style = Document.styles("Titre 2")
                Document.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Range.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = CentimetersToPoints(1) ' Ajoute un alinéa de 1 cm
    
                
                ' Récupérer la plage des descriptions correspondant au sous-chapitre actuel
                lastRowDescription = r.Offset(1, 12).End(xlDown).Row
                Set rngDescription = r.Offset(1, 12).Resize(lastRowDescription - r.Row, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                
                    For Each description In rngDescription
                        ' Vérifier si la description correspond au sous-chapitre actuel
                        If description.Offset(0, -3).Value = sousChapitre.Value Then
                            ' Ajouter la description comme un nouveau paragraphe
                            Document.Content.InsertParagraphAfter
                            Document.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Text = description.Value
                            Document.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Range.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = CentimetersToPoints(1) ' Ajoute un alinéa de 1 cm
                        End If
                    Next description
                End If
                
NextSousChapitre:
            Next sousChapitre
NextChapitre:
            Next chapitre
```

Comment: To enable your question to be understood correctly you need to show examples of how your Word document and Excel data is structured, and what you expect the output of the code to be. Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76322286/edit) link below the question to add the further detail.

Comment: Consider simply using mail merge to insert data. If more complex than that do not use variables to hold your code but subprocedures.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1.

Is your **Document** set up correctly? I don't see in the code you gave me how the Document is set up and what value it is given, so I can't check if it is given the right value.

#### 2.

I can't see any **Bookmarks** in your code, why you said *...adding a bookmark in my Word document...*

> I also tried to place 3 bookmarks to indicate the location where I want the text of my three columns to appear, but knowing that my column 1 corresponds to chapter names, column 2 to subchapter names and column 3 has description names, the problem was that it displayed me all the chapters at bookmark 1, then all the sub-chapter names at bookmark 2, etc, without keeping the correct tree structure.

What I've seen is you used the **Paragraphs** not **Bookmarks** to implement this. Is this what you want to do, or do you want to replace Paragraphs with Bookmarks?

If you want to try to set up a bookmark in a Word document to specify where you want the text to appear, then you can refer to my answer in [this article: Creating automatic fill in word document with drop-down list content control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76245901/8249058) .

#### 3.

These [**Style** property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.paragraph.style) settings are wrong:

```
Document.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Style = Document.Styles("Heading 1")

Document.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Style = Document.Styles("Heading 2")
```

they should be :

```vb
Document.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Style = "Titre 1"

Document.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Style = "Titre 2"
```

or using [**NameLocal** property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.style.namelocal)

```vb
Document.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Style = Document.Styles("Titre 1").NameLocal 

Document.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Style = Document.Styles("Titre 2").NameLocal
```

or using [**WdBuiltinStyle** enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdbuiltinstyle)

```vb
Document.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Style = wdStyleHeading1

Document.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Style = wdStyleHeading2
```

#### 4.

What I've seen is you put the **Value** in the Document, not the **Code**.

```
Document.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Text = chapitre.Value
...
Document.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Text = sousChapitre.Value
...
Document.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Text = description.Value
```

If you are talking about transferring the contents of the code to a specific area of the Document, then why not put the contents of your code in a specific cell, let the code read, and assign it to the variable "VBAcode"? But I really don't know what is the purpose of doing this and what is the use of it?

#### 5.

> ...it into a Word document template. The Word document ...

All I've seen is just a **Document** not a **Template**.

What's the matter with you? What are you talking about, what are you thinking about? And what do you want?